# Possible to access TCP packet details with a go HTTP client?

Tags: go

I have a need to be able to validate TOS/DSCP marks on response data from a set of HTTP servers. Would it be possible, given a list of target URLs to test, if there is a way in `go` to generate the HTTP request, and then be able to examine the response's TCP packet details in order to obtain the TOS value?

My assumption at this point is that it may require creating a socket, and then dynamically generating a TCP packet that contains the HTTP request payload. I've been searching around to see if there were any libraries that would aid in this task, but haven't found anything specific yet.

Note: a simple TCP connection will not provide enough data - the target servers in question will alter TOS/DSCP marks dynamically based on the HTTP server name (so essentially, a single physical server will respond with different TOS marks depending on the vHost requested), so it is important to be able to verify the TOS on actual HTTP response packets, and not something simple like a ping. The TOS values in the TCP 3-way handshake cannot be trusted either - it must be a packet containing the HTTP data.

Comment: TCP is a stream, you can't see actual packets at the application layer. You would need to make normal requests and inspect the packets at a lower layer.

Comment: If you want to generate packets, you probably want to start by looking at https://godoc.org/github.com/google/gopacket

Comment: Yes, I realize that. I guess what I'm wondering is, do I need to do all the work at that low layer, or can I make the HTTP request using higher-level functions, but still have access to the response packets using low-level functions. The old tool I have that does this basically does a `curl`, and then immediately starts snooping packets. It works, but it's not horribly efficient. I'm just investigating some ways to streamline the check at this point.

Comment: I guess one reason I was hoping to be able to make use of the high-level request functions would be TLS, which significantly complicates things if you are generating raw packets (that are expected to work).

Comment: The "simple" way is to do what your curl client does, and sniff the interface during the request. The Go client only needs a `net.Conn` however, so if you can somehow create an instrumented one using `gopacket`, then it could just be dropped into the client.

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps a combination of both `gopacket/pcap` (to do the capture) and `net/http` (to make the request) might work. It would be somewhat analogous to what I'm already doing, but, all in go... and hopefully faster, if I'm lucky.

Comment: If you manage to create the instrumented connection that JimB suggests, [the Transport's DialContext field](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I did end up solving this problem using `gopacket/pcap` and `net/http`.

In a nutshell, what I ended up doing is writing a function that creates a channel, and then calls a goroutine that does the actual packet capture and parsing. The goroutine passes the captured TOS value back to the channel, and then the original function does the http request, and then reads the channel to get the TOS result. Still a bit of a work-in-progress, but so far, this solution seems to be working fairly well.